# Azure authentication with pam_exec

Tags: linux, azure, pam

I am having hard time making this work: I have a python script that performs the required steps in order to get an authorization URL. When I run this script from a terminal, I get back this message from Azure:

```
To sign in, use a web browser to open the page https://aka.ms/devicelogin and enter the code <CODE> to authenticate.
```

Then, the script just stalls until you go to that URL and authenticate or a time out happens. Returned error codes are either 0 (auth succeed) or 1 (auth failed).

The problem is: when I want to use this script for SSH authentication, I use this line in /etc/pam.d/ssh:

```
auth sufficient pam_exec.so stdout <path to script>
```

Which does not work: I never get back the URL to authenticate, and the script just times out. However, if I kill the python process in the server, then I get the URL in the ssh client (although is not useful anymore as the process is not there).

So, seems that pam_exec forwards stdio of the python process, but only when it is terminated, time in which is not useful. Does anybody know how to fix this? Maybe using another pam module? Thank you!

Comment: Hi, do you use `azure login`? If yes, you could try to use non-interactive logon. Please refer to this [example](https://manesh.me/2015/10/15/options-for-azure-cli-logins-step-by-step-guidance/). If no, you had better share this code.

Comment: Hi. No, I do not use azure login, but the problem would be the same: seems pam_exec will just run the program an wait for an exit code 0 for success, and 1 otherwise. As the code is quite irrelevant, as the problem seems to be with pam modules, maybe this question should be moved to ServerFault?

Comment: According to your log, it seems Azure requires you to login firstly, you need login your account in your script. According to your log, I don't think this is a pam issue.

Comment: The script called by pam_exec.so provides a URL and device code and stalls. Then, you go to that URL, with the code, and authenticate yourself. When this happens, the script resumes execution and returns either 0 or 1. The problem is that pam_exec does not forward the stdout of the script until is has exited, at which point the URL is useless.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, I finally understood the whole problem. Seems that SSH (I do not know if the server or the client) packs together all the messages that are not prompts and sends them as a SSH banner message. This means that the either the server or the client are acting as buffers because these are informational messages.

Therefore, the solution has been to send the message as a prompt, as this forces the client to print it as soon as the message is received (and then just discard the user answer).

Comment: Would you happen to be able to share the code you made in order for this to work? I am struggling with the same.

Comment: Even if I remembered where I put that code, I would not be allowed to. However, I remember the only trick was to change a pam_info statement, in the source of pam_exec, to a pam_prompt.